# gdalwarp looses pixel information

Tags: python, raster, gdal, gdalwarp

I have an ungeoreferenced .tif of which I know the spatial information. However, when I run the following command it looses all unique values. All pixels have the value 32, which is the upperleft value.

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -to SRC_METHOD=NO_GEOTRANSFORM -te 5.4990372 46.2904918 15.5783806 55.7887200 -tr 0.020038456088761 0.020038456088761 -r near -overwrite %s %s" % (inputfiles, outputfile)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the most simple, minimal gdalwarp invocation that still exhibits this for you?

Comment: I can leave out the -r near interpolation and the pixel size. produces a raster with a slightly increased pixel size. but still has only 32 as values